# Naming Conventions of Trigonometric Functions

Tags: trigonometry, convention

Anyone who knows trigonometry knows $\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}, \csc(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}, \cot(x)=\frac{1}{\tan(x)}$.

Writing this out in words, we get the following:

- Secant of x = (1 / **CO**sine of x)
- **CO**secant of x = (1 /Sine of x)
- **CO**tangent of x = (1 / Tangent of x)

Here's my question: where do these naming **CO**nventions come from (ignore the pun), what's their history?  And much more importantly, why are the relations (in terms of their names) the way they currently are.  Wouldn't it make more sense for $\sin(x)$ to be related to $\sec(x)$, and $\cos(x)$ to be related to $\csc(x)$?  Or even a more extreme example, like $\sin(x)$ being the reciprocal of $\cos(x)$, $\sec(x)$ being the reciprocal of $\csc(x)$, and $\tan(x)$ being the reciprocal of $\cot(x)$?

And lastly, why were the terms sine, secant, and tangent chosen for their respective meanings?

If you're able to help out, thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You might find a note of mine helpful: ["(Almost) Everything You Need to Remember about Trigonometry, in One Simple Diagram"](http://tricochet.com/math/pdfs/completetriangle.pdf)

Comment: Thank you @Blue.  This does help clarify why the reciprocal relations are the way they actually are (based on the geometry of the "complete triangle" on page one).  However, this does not talk about history of trigonometric naming conventions.

Comment: Co refers to the complimentary angle property.  $\sin(x)=\cos(90^o-x)$

Comment: the cosine of an angle is the sine of its complement etc.

Comment: You really want to get complicated, there are a bunch of other trig function names that are antiquated:  excosine, exsine, versine, coversine, chord, haversine. You really only need either sine or cosine; everything else can be derived from trig identities.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Psh... sine and cosine are too complicated.  All you really need is $\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}$. :P

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum (love the username, latin is an amazing language), where could I learn about these antiquated names?

Comment: A good place to start is the wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine.

Comment: In sanskrit they used the word for chord, which was similar in spelling as the word for bosom so you translated to Latian as "sinus".  cosine refers to the complementary angle.  The length of the tangent line of a circle to the x-axis is $\frac \sin \cos$.  So we can that tangent.  From the original to the point of where the tangent line intersects to x-axis is $\frac 1{\cos}$.  So we call that secant because it cuts the circle and secant means to cut.  It's the only trig identity that confuses me as it is in terms of the COmplentary angle and not the primary one.

Comment: @fleablood The co- functions are the ones that are decreasing between $0$ and $\pi/2$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  I must admit I never noticed that.  Which is a heck of a mnemonic.  But I strongly doubt the any such cconsiderations were the origin of the terms.